# Account Activity Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to know if it is possible to recover gently from the facebook listta of all users logged in (login) made. Estite an API that returns this list as shown in the figure below?:
[image]

thanks for your suppor

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, this is not part of the Facebook Public API.

You will likely need to simulate a browser request on user's behalf to accomplish that, which could well be violating Facebook's TOS.

Comment: Correct, there is no API which reads a user's security and session settings, attempting to scrape such information is pretty likely to trigger the very protections you're trying to get information about, too

Comment: really thanks for the help. I was crazy to try out a possible solution :) 
Can I put your soul in peace :)